# Mod message text doesn't fit in area

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

In some cases, the mod message doesn't fit into the area allocated for it:

> [image]

The image above is taken on iPad 11 Pro latest Chrome, but you can reach the same effect on Windows in Chrome browser just by reducing the window width until the right panel disappears.

[Direct link to the message](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/message/2724#2724) (for staff only).

Comment: That's because of too long profile link, I guess. Btw, looking at the message I cannot reproduce the bug, my browser is the latest Firefox.

Comment: @aepot just try to change the width of the browser's window.

Comment: I tried, everything looks fine. Add more details e.g. browser type and version to the report.

Comment: @aepot updated.

Comment: Possible "fix" is to not include the display name in the URL, it adds nothing, and being encoded, takes tons of space.

Comment: @Adam should we create/find another FR to show decoded username as a link part?

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack It's useful for everyone in the "URLs are for people" camp, such as the [Cool school](https://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Sure. No guarantees on having it addressed soon, but it'd be good to at least have it on the ol' backlog. Thanks!